# stuck taking database offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

On my SQL 2019 server, I right-clicked the database and pick detatch, checked the box drop all active connections, and clicked OK. It's been sitting there for a while now and hasn't gone offline yet.

Looking at the process list, I see sa has a wait of PWAIT_DIRECTLOGCONSUMER_GETNEXT and a cmd of XTP_OFFLINE_CKPT. All of the other processes are normal app processes.

Is that sa process the one preventing the database from going offline? How can I force this to go offline?

Comment: Do you use In-Memory tables?

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably not. How can I tell?

Comment: You'd know if you were, it's a feature (type of table) you'd have to explicitly create in the database.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this task using T-SQL instead of the GUI? Sometimes the GUI can cause this kind of trouble. Also, can you see if there's any process blocking your request using `sp_whoisactive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a backup in progress. Once I canceled the backup, the lock was released and the database went offline.